# How do you do a kick serve?

Tags: tennis, technique, serve

I typically do a hard flat first serve and then a slice second serve, but I'm curious to know the fundamentals behind adding "kick" to a serve for higher bounce.

Comment: How hard do you serve (MPH/KPH)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a rough, elementary answer. It disregards subtleties such as pronation which are relevant to high level play.

The fundamental mechanic behind a tennis serve is that of throwing a ball. In a basic flat serve, your motion is that of throwing a ball forward. In a kick serve, the motion (for a right-handed player) is of throwing a ball to the right. This is usually enough to force the racquet to hit the ball upwards, generating the desired spin.

Answer (score 0):

I never was able to do it until I heard someone say *"Hit the ball up"*. Once I imagined hitting up on the ball, ever so slightly, I started to get them in consistently, and by the end of the night I hit one over my parter's head!

Once you focus on something so simple as that, all the other pieces fall into place, i.e. *brushing the ball*, *7 o'clock-to-1 o'clock motion*, and where to end your follow-through.

Apparently Naomi Osaka's coach uses an interesting drill to drive this point home: